# Observable queue with multiple-scheduler chains: is there an existing solution?

Tags: java, concurrency, rx-java, reactive-programming

I need an observable queue with the following properties:

- Observables execute serially one after another
- Observable can be added to queue **at any time** - dynamically
- Observable can have multiple subscribers attached prior to adding to queue and those subscribers must receive `onNext`/`onError` calls
- Observable can represent a complex operators chain, which might contain http requests, db operations, etc - each running on their own scheduler

That is I have something like this in mind:

```
Observable<?> observable1 = createObservable1()
  .flatMap(v -> executeHttpCall().subscribeOn(HttpScheduler.getInstance()))
  .flatMap(data -> saveToDatabase(data).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .delay(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

// external subscription
observable1
  .subscribe(v -> println("observable1 finished"));

Observable<?> observable2 = createObservable2()
observable2.subscribe(v -> println("observable2 finished"));

ObservableQueue.add(observable1); // <- execution starts immediately (queue is empty)
// 1 second later from other part of the code:
ObservableQueue.add(observable2); // <- execution waits for observable1 to complete and then launches

// expected output: 
// observable1 finished
// observable2 finished
```

I have seen suggestions here on StackOverflow to use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, but that doesn't help in this case, because it doesn't handle well observable chains working on several different schedulers. And this does concern me, because for example `observable1` might write something to DB, and `observable2` is added at the point where that data needs to exist already - so I want to ensure a serial order of executions of **whole chains**.

I wrote a [simple implementation](https://gist.github.com/dimsuz/a942288ab27d518ba437) of this with coordination happening using Subjects (btw, feedback is very welcome), but I wanted to ask if anyone knows an exisiting solution which I could use instead of inventing my own.

Comment: Sounds like that `observable2` directly depends on a runtime value produced by `observable1`.
That is the whole reason `flatMap` exists, monads are sequential by nature.
If `observable2` is independent of `observable1`'s runtime values, I'd also suggest running them on some queue-like `Scheduler`.

Comment: @NizamutdinovAdel no, they are considered independent. They can be added/executed  at different points in time. `observable1` might be already completed when second one is added to the queue. Running them on some single thread Scheduler is not an option, I explained why in the question.

Comment: Can you confirm - you don't want execution to start when the Observables are subscribed to (assuming cold Observables), but when they are taken from the head of the queue? If so - why?

Comment: @Will Well, they maybe subscribed to right away, but they should start producing items only after they get to the head of the queue. The reason is that I'd like to have a several *independent* and dynamically added observables to operate one after another in a serial fashion. Each can have its own subscriber in different part of an application.